# How do I set a breakpoint on operator< with GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

Basically what the title says. I have a function:

```
bool operator< (... lhs, ... rhs)
```

that I would like to break on. 'b operator<(...)' gives me the error:

```
malformed template specification in command
```

How can I stop GDB from thinking the < is a template opener? I've tried to set a breakpoint by line number as well, but this definition is in a header file, and for some reason, GDB thinks that line number doesn't exist in the header file.

GDB 6.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could first print all occurrences of operator `<`, grab the address of the function you're interested and set a breakpoint on it.

**NOTE:** This technique would work irrespective of your function definition is in `.h` or `.cpp` file as long as you have compiled with `g++` using `-g`

```
$ gdb test

(gdb) p 'operator <'
$1 = {bool (MyClass &, MyClass &)} 0x4009aa <operator<(MyClass&, MyClass&)>

(gdb) b *0x4009aa
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4009aa: file test.h, line 5.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/agururaghave/.scratch/gdb-test/test 

Breakpoint 1, operator< (obj1=..., obj2=...) at test.cpp:6
6           friend bool operator < ( MyClass &obj1, MyClass &obj2 ) {
```

I tested out with the following code:

```
/* test.h */
#include <iostream>
class MyClass {
public:
    friend bool operator < ( MyClass &obj1, MyClass &obj2 ) {
        std::cout << "operator <" << "\n";  
        return true;
    }
};

/* test.cpp */    
#include "test.h"
int main() {
    MyClass myObj1;
    MyClass myObj2;

    bool result = myObj1 < myObj2;

    std::cout << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting it in single-quotes:

```
break 'operator<(Blah, Blah)'
```

You can also use TAB-completion to get GDB to help you

If that doesn't help you'll need to be more specific about the operator's signature instead of saying "...", since you're omitting the important part of the question!

Oh, I've just seen you're using GDB 6.8 which is about to celebrate its 5th birthday ... upgrade. GDB 7 is much better at parsing C++ declarations.

Comment: Single quotes didn't work, and when I tried tab completion, I saw that this operator fucntion isn't even being listed at all by GDB. Let me do some testing to see if it's actually being used... I wish I could upgrade GDB, but I'm debugging remotely on a server I don't have root on.

Comment: Ok, I moved the definitions to the cpp file and was able to set a breakpoint by line number, but still not by symbol, same errors as before. The bigger problem seems to be that this function is never called, which explains why my multiset is so effed up...

Comment: You don't need root to install gdb, just install it in your home dir and run it from there