# gdb: search function by name to set a breakpoint

Tags: gdb, stdout, breakpoints

I'm trying to find out what part of a program prints to **stdout**.

I can set a breakpoint using command like:
`b std::ostream::operator<<(int)`

but when i type: `b std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&)` no breakpoint is created.

So there are two questions:

1. How to set a breakpoint on `operator << (..., cosnt std::string&)` ?
2. I want to set a breakpoint, but i don't know the exact name of the function. How to search for a function using **regexp** or part of its name ?

Comment: answer from a colleague:
http://tdistler.com/2008/11/13/debugging-c-templates-brekpoints-and-gdb

The quick answer: use objdump, c++filt, and grep to find the complete definition that GDB will need.

$ objdump -t libMyLib.so | c++filt | grep ‘BarAbstract.*Baz’
0000d2d6 w F .text 0000000a     MY_PLUGIN_A::Foo<MY_PLUGIN_A::BarAbstract>::Baz()

Now, simply copy-n-paste the full method definition to GDB when setting the breakpoint:

(gdb) b MY_PLUGIN_A::Foo<MY_PLUGIN_A::BarAbstract>::Baz()
Breakpoint 6 at 0×8048890: file Source/Bar.cpp, line 355

Comment: breakpoint on operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301924/how-do-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-operator-with-gdb Break on regexp: `rbreak regexp`.

Answer (score 16):

Use "**info functions <<.*string**" to search for functions with **<<** and **string** in their names. **info functions** takes a regular expression as argument.

Then select from the listed functions the one you want. Remove the **;** at the end of the declaration if any and paste the declaration as an argument to the **break** command:

```
$ gdb -q ./ostream-operator-breakpoint 
<...>

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4006b0: file ostream-operator-breakpoint.cc, line 4.
Starting program: /home/scottt/Dropbox/stackoverflow/ostream-operator-breakpoint 
<...>

(gdb) info functions <<.*string
All functions matching regular expression "<<.*string":

File /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.7.2-20121109/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > &std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&);
std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> > &std::operator<< <wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >&, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&);

(gdb) break std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > &std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
Breakpoint 2 at 0x3cbfa94640: file /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.7.2-20121109/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h, line 2750.
```

The **start** (or **run**) command is required for dynamically linked programs. Unless you first start the inferior process, **info functions** wouldn't list functions from shared libraries such as libstdc++.